# how list just one file from a (bash) shell directory listing

Tags: bash, shell, file-handling

A bit lowly a query but here goes:
bash shell script. POSIX, Mint 21

I just want one/any (mp3) file from a directory. As a sample.
In normal execution, a full run, the code would be such

```
for f in *.mp3 do
  #statements
done
```

This works fine but if I wanted to sample just one file of such an array/glob (?) without looping, how might I do that? I don't care which file, just that it is an mp3 from the directory I am working in.
Should I just start this for-loop and then exit(break) after one statement, or is there a neater way more tailored-for-the-job way?

```
for f in *.mp3 do
  #statement
  break
done
```

Ta (can not believe how dopey I feel asking this one, my forehead will hurt when I see the answers )

Comment: I would first store all filenames into an array and then pick a random element from the array, for instance using the bash variable `$RANDOM`.

Comment: `arr=(*.mp3); f="${arr[0]}"`? But is it that much better than your own solution? Note: use `shopt -s nullglob` if there is a risk that you have no `*.mp3` files.

Comment: The OP's code with `break` seems superior to me. Why would you collect the matches into memory if you don't care what they are?

Comment: I will look into that 'random' idea - random is not required though - and the array creation is at  handy for other applications (I'm learning stuff), I didn't know such simple "globbing" was possible even "for f in *.mp3" seemed non-specific to me compared with python glob. But this is what I like about shell scripting, it's like I am there on the command line. @tripleee your comment helps me see the balance of what is "better". appreciate you all

Comment: @Dee As you've specified POSIX in the question then I think that you need to know that a POSIX shell doesn't have "arrays"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Linux (Mint) you've got GNU `find` so one way to get one `.mp3` file from the current directory is:

```
mp3file=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.mp3' -printf '%f' -quit)
```

- `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` causes the search to be restricted to one level under the current directory.
- `-printf '%f'` prints just the filename (e.g. `foo.mp3`).  The `-print` option would print the path to the filename (e.g. `./foo.mp3`).  That may not matter to you.
- `-quit` causes `find` to exit as soon as one match is found and printed.

Another option is to use the Bash [:](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_003a) (colon) command and [$_](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0024_005f) (dollar underscore) special variable:

```
: *.mp3
mp3file=$_
```

- `: *.mp3` runs the `:` command with the list of `.mp3` files in the current directory as arguments.  The `:` command ignores its arguments and does nothing.
- `mp3file=$_` sets the value of the `mp3file` variable to the last argument supplied to the previous command (`:`).

The second option should not be used if the number of `.mp3` files is large (hundreds or more) because it will find all of the files and sort them by name internally.

In both cases `$mp3file` should be checked to ensure that it really exists (e.g. `[[ -e $mp3file ]]`) before using it for anything else, in case there are no `.mp3` files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this in POSIX shell:

```
mp3file=
for f in *.mp3; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        mp3file=$f
        break
    fi
done
# At this point, the variable mp3file contains a filename which
# represents a regular file (or a symbolic link) with the .mp3
# extension, or empty string if there is no such a file.
```

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you use

```
for f in *.mp3 do
```

suggests to me, that the MP3s are named without to much strange characters in the filename.

In that case, if you really don't care which MP3, you could:

```
f=$(ls *.mp3|head)
statement
```

Or, if you want a different one every time:

```
f=$(ls *.mp3|sort -R | tail -1)
```

Note: if your filenames get more complicated (including spaces or other special characters), this will not work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't have spaces in your filenames, (and I don't understand why the collective taboo is against using ls in scripts at all, rather than not having spaces in filenames, personally) then:-

```
ls *.mp3 | tr ' ' '\n' | sed -n '1p'
```